# Reverting commits after merge

Tags: git, version-control

I am working on dev branch and I merged dev into master so all the commits not appear on master but I am not very confident about some thing. Should I do pull request and then merge or this way is fine? Because master branch looks dirty now with other branches commits. Should I do revert and then do this?

Comment: In Git, commits *aren't* on branches.

Comment: look into the command: git rebase -i

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I totally follow, but it seems like what you're asking is if there's a way for branch commits to not appear on master. If that's the question, then no - when you merge your branch into master, all of the commits from that branch will be added to the master branch as well.

Something that may be a solution to what you're describing is rebasing/squashing commits. It's a somewhat-common practice to squash all commits in a dev branch before merging to master. This keeps the master branch clean (as you want) by giving each commit the context of of a full piece of work, not bits and pieces.

[This](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) is my go-to reference when people have slightly-more-than-basic git questions.